# Google maps Api en socket lo, limites

Tags: javascript, google-maps, socket.io

bueno, estoy desarrollando una app que se comunica a través de socket.io de node para mostrar la ruta entre 2 puntos.

Por lo que vi Google maps es gratis hasta las 2500 request del servicio "directions", ahora mí duda es, ya que estaré utilizando un socket, Google como cobra las peticiones en estos casos?, Yo puedo hacer que cada 1 minuto haga una nueva petición de ruta para intentar no consumir muchas.

Pero alguien que tenga experiencia con esto y me puedo explicar?

Gracias